# How do you prevent a process from automatically restarting? (specifically, sophos antivirus)

Tags: macos, mac

I am required by my VPN software to have Sophos anti-virus installed and running.  However, when I'm NOT on VPN, I don't want it running at all - I want it dead.

However, killing the tasks is ineffective:

```
ps -ax | grep -i soph
40972 ??         0:07.34 /Library/Sophos Anti-Virus/SophosAutoUpdate.app/Contents/MacOS/SophosAutoUpdate -d
41069 ??        28:08.48 /Library/Sophos Anti-Virus/InterCheck.app/Contents/MacOS/InterCheck -d
41078 ??         0:02.42 /Library/Sophos Anti-Virus/SophosAntiVirus.app/Contents/MacOS/SophosAntiVirus -d
$ sudo kill 40972 41069 41078 41084
$ ps -ax | grep -i soph
44344 ??         0:00.03 /Library/Sophos Anti-Virus/SophosAutoUpdate.app/Contents/MacOS/SophosAutoUpdate -d
44345 ??         0:00.02 /Library/Sophos Anti-Virus/SophosAntiVirus.app/Contents/MacOS/SophosAntiVirus -d
44347 ??         0:03.03 /Library/Sophos Anti-Virus/InterCheck.app/Contents/MacOS/InterCheck -d
```

It just automatically restarts.  What do I need to do to prevent that?

Comment: It is possible there is a preference in the Sophos software to turn it off?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell; if it's there, it's hidden.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This means that there is another monitor process which relaunches it.

You can check out who is the parent process: select the process in activity monitor and use the Info button, or via terminal with `ps -ax -O ppid` if I recall correctly.

- It might be another process by Sophos but with a stealth name, or maybe even your VPN software. In that case you can just `kill`'em all.
- The other possibility is that the process is being kept alive by the launch daemon `launchd`. In this case you will find an entry (a plist XML file) for your antivirus in either `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchAgents` (likely) or `/System/Library/LaunchAgents` (I dearly hope not).

If the second is the case, you can either:

- Edit the file, and change the KeepAlive parameter, either removing or changing it (you can do nifty things, see [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) for more).
- Just ask launchd to do the stopping for you. Unfortunately you can't just tell to `launchtl stop` since the process would just respawn. You'll have to use 
   `sudo launchctl unload /path/to/the/plist file`

Comment: Thanks Agos, that's exactly the advice I was looking for.  However, I can't find the darn thing!  There are no PIDs with numbers near (the original, pre-killed) Sophos Anti-Virus that I can associate with it.  Nothing turned up in the LaunchAgents directories (though all I did was a simple regex check in /System/).  Is there any log file in which launchd would record restarting a process?  I've checked system.log and others without luck...

Comment: The file for me was here `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.sophos.common.servicemanager.plist` - you can find via `mdfind -name Sophos`. Removing the Keep Alive parameter worked.

Comment: Doesn't work for processes in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons - OSX gives you an error "Could not find specified service"

Answer (score 7):

I'd comment on Agos' post, but I'm too new to do that. So:

As far as I remember they should have a launch agent in `/Library/LaunchAgents`. I'd just ask you to do a `ls /Library/LaunchAgents`, `ls /Library/LaunchDaemons` and `ls /System/Library/LaunchDaemons`. Something **will** show up.

Also you could open `/Applications` and check Uninstall Sophos.app with `Show Package Contents` then check out the uninstall script.

Comment: Thanks Ghost.  The directory Agos left out was /Library/LaunchDaemons, which has the plist file.  I gave you a +1, but Agos the answer, since he got most of it. I greatly appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Make sure you run spotlight to look for Sophos files left  behind after the 'uninstall' mdfind -name Sophos

Comment: @chiggsy why would he do that? He doesn't want to uninstall the application but prevent it from restarting every time he kills it.

Comment: That's it? That's all he wants?

Answer (score 4):

```
man launchctl


launchctl list |grep -i 'sophos'
```

to unload a daemon permanently, but not uninstall it

```
launchctl unload -w /full/path/to/file.plist
```

Comment: This is the "better" answer because it will also prevent it from loading ever (-w)

Comment: sophos hides.  This doesn't work on sophos.

Answer (score 1):

To find out which `launchd` job is spawning things back, `tail -f /var/log/system.log` and `sudo kill -9 <pid>` the process you are interested in.

Suddenly, `launchd` will tell you exactly which job is responsible:

```
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.sophos.managementagent[83911]): Exited: Killed: 9
```

You can also try increasing the log level to precisely determine what's happening: `launchctl log level debug`

Bear in mind that some jobs will be run as `root`, so `sudo launchctl list` might show you some extra jobs running on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also control which Launch Agent and Daemons run and when with the useful app Lingon, available through the Mac App store and online.